# writing a function which creates a string (javascript) and then add it to a button as its attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a Button in my .aspx web form and use c# 3.0
I want to add a javascript function to its attribute as its "onclick" event handler.
the function has 1 parameter in order to check whether onclick javascript should get a confirmation from user or not. The parameter Datatype is bool But when I send true, 
execution of the program halts and show me a message that True is not defined!!

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*True* needs to be lowercase in javascript.

Comment: so you say I should declare a string variable and make lowercase of the input parameter?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what your objects look like exactly, but should be able to do it something like this:

onclick="myJsFunction(<%=Datatype.ToString().ToLower();  %>); return false;"

or perhaps just do some conditional logic on the bool:

onclick="myJsFunction(<%=Datatype ? "true" : "false" %>); return false;"